# Correctness of proof for the convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the following series converge?

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5^n + (-1)^n}{2^n3^n}$

What I've done so far.

$0\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5^n + (-1)^n}{2^n3^n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5^n + 1^n}{6^n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^n$

We know that last two series both converge, since they are an instance of a geometric series with both $|q|<1$.

Now from this, am I allowed to conclude that the original series converges? What stops it from alternating between 0 and the sum of the values of the geometric series?

Comment: Note that $5^n + (-1)^n > 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: IThe partial sums are **increasing**.

Comment: Use absolute convergence.

Comment: I'd like to know whether the proof above is correct or not. Can you help me with this?

Comment: You can just see that the series is absolutely convergent $\implies$ it is convergent.

Comment: Yes, your work is fine.  And it cannot alternate in sign since $5^n>(-1)^{n+1}$ for all $n\ge1$.  Thus, the terms in the series are positive.

Comment: Thanks Dr. MV. Now I also get the comment of André Nicolas. So if I use the sandwich theorem and the lower and upper series do converge, but not towards the same value, then I need the series to be monotonically increasing or decreasing in order to conclude that it converges (in case it should alternate, we could not conclude directly that the series converges).

Comment: @André Nicolas: Could you post it as an answer? So I can close the question.

Comment: It was just a comment, and Daniel Fischer made an equivalent comment first. For completeness, the partial sums are increasing, and are bounded above by your sum of two geometric series. So the partial sums converge. But this last part is covered by a standard theorem, so after the theorem is proved, it need not be mentioned explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, we have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{5^n+(-1)^n}{2^n\cdot 3^n}$$ $$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{5^n+(-1)^n}{6^n}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{5^n}{6^n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{6^n}$$ 
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{-1}{6}\right)^n$$

$$=\left(\frac{5}{6}+\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2+\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3+\ldots\right)+\left(\frac{-1}{6}+\left(\frac{-1}{6}\right)^2+\left(\frac{-1}{6}\right)^3+\ldots\right)$$ $$=\left(\frac{\frac{5}{6}}{1-\frac{5}{6}}\right)+\left(\frac{-\frac{1}{6}}{1-\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right)}\right)$$ 
$$=\left(\frac{\frac{5}{6}}{\frac{1}{6}}\right)+\left(\frac{-\frac{1}{6}}{\frac{7}{6}}\right)$$ 
$$=5-\frac{1}{7}=\frac{35-1}{7}$$ $$=\frac{34}{7}$$ Above is a finite value. Hence the series converges.